# Unwinding two lists and matching row indices together?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I unwind two lists and match the results using their indices? I have the code below:

```
UNWIND [SPAT, TNAVPS, UPBT] AS metapart1
UNWIND [cell2.content] AS metapart2
```

metapart1 represents a list of 3 strings that were defined earlier on in the query (which I can't show due to confidential reasons), while metapart2 comprises of only three possible values given the conditions stated earlier in the query. For clarity, the values are 273.3, 192.1, and 2.97. I want to map elements from the two lists together specifically such that metapart1 + metapart2 results in a desired output; e.g. 'value of SPAT is 273.3', 'value of TNAVPS is 192.1', but not return 'value of TNAVPS is 273.3' if that makes sense.

I'm cognisant of the fact that UNWINDing two lists results in the output being every permutation of elements from each list (e.g. unwinding [1,2,3] and [4,5,6] results in 1 and 4, 1 and 5, 1 and 6, 2 and 4, etc.) but I don't know how to work around this in any way.

For additional clarity, cell2.content is specified in the main bulk of the query so I can't define it with a WITH clause at the start of the query, so not really sure what to do

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate thru each item in meta1 and meta2 and combine them into one collection.  I don't have a copy of your own query so ensure that both m1 and m2 are collections.

> 1. Define m1 and m2 as collections
> 2. Iterate from each items in the list m1 and m2 then concatenate each items
> 3. Return the data per row

```
WITH ['SPAT', 'TNAVPS', 'UPBT'] AS m1, [273.3, 192.1, 2.97] AS m2
WITH [i in range(0, size(m1)-1) | 'value of ' + toString(m1[i]) + ' is ' + toString(m2[i])] as allMeta
UNWIND allMeta as meta
RETURN meta

Result:
╒══════════════════════════╕
│"meta"                    │
╞══════════════════════════╡
│"value of SPAT is 273.3"  │
├──────────────────────────┤
│"value of TNAVPS is 192.1"│
├──────────────────────────┤
│"value of UPBT is 2.97"   │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: The only issue with that is that if I specify WITH halfway through the query, any part of the query that comes before that WITH just gets ignored and gives me a load of 'variable not defined'

Comment: you will add the rest of the variables on WITH statement. I cannot give you the query that will work because you gave us only a part of your query. You need to fix your query and add the small query that I gave you.